# Android: Multiple IntentServices - stopService

Tags: android, intentservice

I am starting an IntentService several times with a unique id value. When I recreate the intent and use it to call stopService on the current IntentService, the entire IntentService queue is cancelled on top of stopping the current IntentService. Also, calling stopService on an IntentService that is in the queue, has no effect.

Start Service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, IntentService.class);
intent.putExtra("action", "scan");
intent.putExtra("id", id);
context.startService(intent);
```

Stop Service

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, IntentService.class);
intent.putExtra("action", "scan");
intent.putExtra("id", id);
context.stopService(intent);
```

I would like the IntentService with the associated id to be stopped / removed from queue, then have the rest of the queue run its course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have to implement your own type of intent service here. [Looking at the code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java)

Although looking at the `stopSelf(int)` method, you might be able to do this manually if you know what each intent is created with.

```
mActivityManager.stopServiceToken(
                new ComponentName(this, mClassName), mToken, startId);
```

So something like:

```
mActivityManager.stopServiceToken(
                new ComponentName(this, IntentService.class.getSimpleName()), null, mStartId);
```

I haven't tried this but might be a nudge in the right direction. Although I think that it might not do anything as it will only stop running services.

Otherwise you will have to make your own IntentService where you can fire remove intents at it.. might be worth nudging @commonsguy

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: @meeeee did you get anywhere with this, I would be interested to see the result as I'm thinking I might need something similar in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I extented a normal service where everytime startService is called I add the intent to an arraylist and start the worker thread if not already started. The worker thread loops through all the intents, I also call startService with an intent using a flag to remove another intent from the queue(arraylist).

Comment: @meeeee OK I thought that might be what would have to be done. Sounds good.